Trying to deploy my docker images to my server through gitlab cicd
Last couple of days I've been trying to make my cicd for my project on gitlab to work.
I had this script that actually worked before but all of sudden it does not work anymore.
Only thing i had to change was ssh keys because of new machine. Basically I created on my local machine ssh keys, then I add private key to the variables in gitlab cicd and then I add the public key to authorized keys on my server.
Am I doing wrong steps with ssh keys ?
stages:
  - pre_build
  - deploy_image

pre_build:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  stage: pre_build
  only:
    - dev
  before_script:
    - |
      apt-get -yq update
      apt-get -yq install curl
      apt-get -y install jq
  script:
    - |
      echo $SOME_SERVER_ADDRESS
      host=$(curl $SOME_SERVER_ADDRESS)
      ip=$(echo $host | jq '.ip')
      ip=$(echo $ip | tr -d '"')
      echo "Fetched ip address"
      echo $ip
      echo "SERVER_IP=$ip" >> prebuild.env

  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: prebuild.env

#url to check for tutorial https://karol-filipczuk.medium.com/#gitlab-ci-cd-pipeline-run-script-via-ssh-to-remote-server-9594f326bc2f
deploy_image:
  image: docker/compose:latest
  stage: deploy_image
  only:
    - main
  before_script:
    - |
      echo "Server address to deploy docker $SERVER_IP"
      docker-compose --version
      docker context create remote --docker "host=ssh://$SSH_NAME_DELL@$SERVER_IP"
      command -v ssh-agent > /dev/null || (apk add --update openssh)
      mkdir -p ~/.ssh
      chmod 700 ~/.ssh
      eval $(ssh-agent -s)
      echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DELL" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
      touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      ssh-keyscan $SERVER_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - |
      docker --context remote ps
      docker context use remote
      ls
      docker-compose --context remote up --force-recreate --build -d
      docker image prune -f
  dependencies:
    - "pre_build"

This is the exception that i keep getting.
  [52] Failed to execute script docker-compose
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 125, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 76, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 142, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 47, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 174, in docker_client
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 166, in __init__
  File "site-packages/docker/transport/sshconn.py", line 111, in __init__
  File "site-packages/docker/transport/sshconn.py", line 119, in _connect
  File "site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 446, in connect
  File "site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 764, in _auth
  File "site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 700, in _auth
  File "site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1580, in auth_publickey
  File "site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 250, in wait_for_response
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

